# MySql and Php with xcode

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I'm trying to make a ios app that will connect to a external database to update the app with current information. I'm really new to this and I've been searching for an answer for a while now. So one of my question is can I connect my app with my localhost? or would it be more efficient to do it another way? also I made a database with phpmyadmin but I'm not sure if this method is the best way to go about the problem. Also where do I place my .php file to connect to the database? I was looking at awardspace.com. Would this work for my problem? My question may have not made complete sense because I'm trying to learn but I'm experiencing a lot of problems.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service and http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app.

Comment: @Rob that article is quite outdated, as for example it suggests using ASIHTTPRequest which is not maintained anymore.

Comment: @Qualcuno Agreed. Nowadays you'd probably use AFNetworking instead of ASIHTTPRequest. But it outlines the basic design considerations of writing a client for iOS and writing a database-driven web service. Seems like OP is asking for a bit of primer on the topic. This question is far too broad for S.O. answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two separate and distinct layers.

- An iOS application written in Objective-C or Swift, developed using Xcode.
- A backend on a remote server, written for example in PHP/MySQL (but any other language would work) that returns the data.

The iOS app will make requests to the remote server like normal HTTP requests. The web server will receive the input and respond with the proper data.

For example, if you want to get a list of items, you will have your iOS app make a HTTP request to `http://example.com/list`. On that remote server, a PHP script will connect to the database and respond with all the data requested. Normally you don't output HTML code, but instead it's a good idea to use JSON (other formats are available, like XML, BSON, protobuf... however, JSON is extremely simple to use with basically any modern language, it's human-readable and it's quite efficient too).
You may want to check out [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com), a very powerful yet really simple library for iOS/OSX apps that makes HTTP requests extremely easy to deal with.

The PHP script must not be on your localhost, as only your computer will be able to connect to it (so, only the iOS simulator). You can use localhost for development, but then you will need to get a server.

Another option for you to consider is using one of those many "MBaaS" (*Mobile Backend as a Service*) services, which are getting really popular. An example is [Parse](https://www.parse.com) (now owned by Facebook), [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com) and many, many more (and new companies are emerging every day).